# Android - Does R.Resource ID changes in runtime

Tags: android

I have number of `drawables` to select in a `View`. When the user selects one of the `drawable` and on next time when the app is launch , I have to show only the selected drawable.

Is it good to store the `Resource ID` in shared preference and retrieve the selected drawable using `Resource ID` next time when the app is launched.?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All the R class related ids are generated at compile time so they won't change at runtime.  There's nothing stopping you from storing this IDs in SharedPreferences, however, there's no gain whatsoever.  It's almost always faster just to reference the R.drawable.x related id.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but I'd advise AGAINST storing the values in SharedPreferences.

When you release a newer version of the app, it's re-compiled. There is no guarantee, that the old value of let's say R.drawable.ic_example has the same value when drawables have been added/removed to the updated application. Therefore the stored value could no longer match with the Drawable asset you expect.